# Why does Frobenius norm make BFGS scale-invariant?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

On slide 11 [here](http://terminus.sdsu.edu/SDSU/Math693a_f2013/Lectures/18/lecture.pdf)
it is claimed that the weighted Frobenius norm leads to a scale-invariant optimization method. Similar claims about this norm can be found throughout the literature see [1](http://tocs.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/83944087.pdf),[2](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9781118723203),[3](https://people.csail.mit.edu/jsolomon/share/book/numerical_book.pdf).

In Greenstadt's original [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1970-24-109/S0025-5718-1970-0258248-4/) the Weighted Frobenius norm is proposed without mention of its relation to scale-invariance. It is claimed that this norm is scale-invariant. That I take to mean for any linear transformation $T$, matrix $A$ has the same norm as matrix $TA$. I am not even sure this is is true (plug in the identity matrix for the weight matrix $W$). Perhaps I got the wrong invariance definition.

I have yet to found what exactly is this scale-invariance referring to. It's proof is supposed to be very straightforward because no one seemed to think it necessary to be written down explicitly.

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

I think they mention "scale invariant" in the context that with the given choice of $W$, you get (see next slide):

$$B_{k+1}=(I-\gamma_k\bar{y}_k\bar{s}_k^T)B_k\cdots$$

where,

$$\gamma_k=\frac{1}{\bar{y}_k^T\bar{s}_k}.$$

Then $\gamma_k \bar{y}_k\bar{s}_k^T$ and related quantities are unitless

Comment: What does it have to do with the Weighted Frobenius norm though? What is the intrinsic invariance property of this norm ?